# Efficient way of unsorting an array I sorted myself

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

In my application, I let users choose how they want their data arranged (sorted or unsorted).
When they choose sorted, I simply sort everything. That part is straightforward to me.

However, when they choose sorted, and then choose unsorted, I want to show them the data in the same order that the database gave it to me (i.e. I don't want to just call randomize() or something).
Is there an efficient way of "unsorting" an array that I sorted myself without maintaing a copy of the original array?

Comment: What is "data"? Is it an array of values, an object, HTMLCollection, what?

Comment: I think in case of **unsorted** I would sort them using `Record.ID` or `Record.creationTimestamp`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing you could do is keep an extra (hidden) integer value in each record which records the original order that you received the records from the database. When the user chooses "unsorted", then sort by that original-order value.

Comment: Note that if you don't want to add a new field, keeping a *copy* of the entire array is not necessary either. You only need an array of "inverse-sorted" indices (an array of 0.. *n* indexes sorted along with your data).

Comment: @Jongware—do you have any code to show how to maintain the unsorted indices? I think there's a bit more to "only" than you've inferred. :-)

Comment: My suggestion would be to use database indexing

Comment: @RobG: Ah, the dangers of Late Night posting. I believe I meant this: sort the array of *indexes* only. Then you can use this to display the sorted data -- only rearrange the data if necessary (if so, the sorted indexes can also be used to undo sorting).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just keep a copy of the original collection? Or just never modify it in place and instead generate sorted copies of the original collection as the user requests sorting. This seems like much simpler than keeping an original-order value or something like that.

Comment: 1. I don't want to save another copy of the array because it could end up being pretty large.  

2. This is the reverse of what I'm doing now (I'm requesting all the data again when the user want's them unsorted).  

Both would work, but I'm looking for a better (if more complicated) solution.

Comment: In that case, Greg's answer is probably the way to go.